# Hiding input variables from ever being recorded in a transaction

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I'm working on something, just a proof of concept, where people are rewarded for sharing metadata about their IP location.  In this case (please ignore the code errors for now), someone would submit their ip, I would send it to an oracle that would resolve it and send back metadata about the ip, then would send the address and metadata to another contract.

This is the naive attempt at pseudo code (or non-compiling, at least) I've come up with:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

import "github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/oraclizeAPI.sol";


contract IpMeta is usingOraclize {

    uint public metadata;

    function Metadata(bytes32 _ipAddress) public {
        update(_ipAddress);
    }

    function __callback(bytes32 myid, string result) public {
        if (msg.sender != oraclize_cbAddress()) revert();
        bytes32 ipMetadata = result;
        /* send address and result to another contract */
    }

    function update(bytes32 ipAddress) public payable {
        oraclize_query("URL", "xml(https://ipresolver.com?ipresolve=" . ipAddress . ")");
    }
}
```

The goal here is to allow people to prove something about their IP address (country, provider, etc) without the actual IP address being stored with the wallet address in the transaction or anywhere else.  Is there a way to hide input data?  I'm at a loss on research, and it seems like it would be a really useful function if possible.  The im/practicalities of anything other than how to keep input data hidden or inaccessible aren't important.

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

The EVM is essentially a network composed of nodes of computers. Anyone can run their own node and your smart contract code will get run on those computers if they have a valid node that can receive the transactions. And since the data will also get transmitted to those computers, the owner that sees the code running in his/her computer will eventually have the power to look into the process getting run(by overseeing network, inspecting memory, etc.).

So from my understanding, the difficulty of doing this depends on the implementation of a Ethereum node. Actually Ethereum's protocols handles some level of security by [encrypting the p2p connection](https://github.com/ethereumproject/go-ethereum/wiki/RLPx-Encryption). However, what makes all these obsolete in your context is that, the input data is serviced and revealed by services like etherscan([random example](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x1b74d7df2b9a88b1ada7a51e86bfc41279bda1831fea86a83eac2b35e13bb4ac)). I think it's still possible to achieve want you want, but it will only be a workaround and it will be difficult.

I think of Ethereum and its EVM as a transparent computer, basically the data it receives and sends are not secure at all. If you want to achieve security, that's the thing to achieve in somewhere else, for example process the ip related jobs in some other secure place(trusted 3rd party), then store the data without ip onto the blockchain. That's the best I can think of.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yeah, we kind of came to that conclusion also. We looked into some commit/reveal patterns, but they fall short also. karl.tech/learning-solidity-part-2-voting.  The third-party workaround is the best we could come up with, but then we're out of a true "trustless" relationship with the users.  Our main goal here was to try and develop something that was achievable only on the blockchain, and not just repurposing a good ol' database on the blockchain.  Really appreciate the thought and the reply!

Comment: @Mark Yeah, I recommend to look into hardware attestation if you still want to implement this. https://blog.oraclize.it/welcoming-our-brand-new-ledger-proof-649b9f098ccc There is a service called oraclize which provides data from non-blockchain context. They implemented the feature with so-called "ledger-proof" solution with helper of "Ledger", which provides a hardware that guarantees the execution of certain code. So it's possible but cumbersome. You may want to head up to that. Wish you a good luck!

Comment: Thanks, @viz!  Will look into it!  Will report back to the thread if we find anything.